# Check out a repository from TFS via the command line

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to write a script (which will eventually be used in TeamCity) to check out a project from TFS via the command line. It should do this afresh each time i.e. create local workspace mapped to a working directory.

I've found the page *[Workspace Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y901w7se(v=vs.100).aspx)*, and I believe I need to use the `workspace` command probably followed by `checkout`, but I'm not 100% sure. So far I have tried:

```
tf workspace /new <MyMachineName>;<WindowsUsername> /noprompt
/collection:https://<myrepo>.visualstudio.com:8080/DefaultCollection/MyProject
/permission:Private
/location:local
/filetime:checkin
/login:<TfsUsername>,<TfsPassword>
```

which results in the error

> TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server  https://myrepo.visualstudio.com:8080/DefaultCollection/MyProject.
>   Technical information (for administrator):
>     Unable to connect to the remote server

I am using the developer command prompt for Visual Studio 2012, and I *am* able to browse the repository via the web interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 8080 port is used for the on-premise TFS Server. If you are using Visual Studio Team Service, you need to remove it from the URL.

Try with following URL:

```
/collection:https://<YOURAccount>.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `/collection` flag should only go as far https://myrepo.visualstudio.com:8080/DefaultCollection (i.e., you shouldn't specify a project here)

Next you'll have to use [tf Workfold](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fa04bx6(v=vs.100).aspx) to specify where on the local machine you want to map the workspace and which server folder you want to map (maybe in this case it's everything under `$/MyProject` or some sub-folder of it).

Finally you'll need to do a [tf get](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf(v=vs.100).aspx) to pull the files down to the new workspace on the local machine.

Comment: Thanks for outlining the required steps for me. I tried changing the `/collection` property as you suggested, but am still getting the same error.

Comment: Sorry that didn't help, I can't repro your error but is probably a messed up cache or something (delete cache: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsalm/archive/2013/12/17/how-to-clear-the-tfs-cache-on-client-machines.aspx).  Another thing to note is that  tf.exe is probably ignoring the /login flag and using your cached credentials instead.

Comment: I've tried clearing the cache already, but interesting point about it using cached credentials

Comment: Can you elaborate on the first sentence? And make it more clear what is meant?